# Cannot convert from type T to type T?

Tags: java

A strange error here using static factory pattern. What am I missing?  Here is the code:

```
class subclass<T> extends immutablestruct<T>{
private immutablestruct f;
private T x;

    //constructor
<T> subclass(T y, immutablestruct<T> f ){
    this.x = y;  //this is there the error is
    this.f = f;
}
```

Comment: no all-lowercase class names, please

Comment: maybe it'll compile if you use lowercase `t` instead of `T`

Answer (score 10):

Remove `<T>` from constructor declaration. Now you're declaring second generic parameter, while you can access old `T` value:

```
//constructor
subclass(T y, immutablestruct<T> f ){
```